The correct way to initialize PCI device manually
A Linux kernel PCI device driver would usually call pci_register_driver() and get a callback via ->probe(). In this callback we would use pci_enable_device(), pci_set_master() and finally request_irq().
I have noticed when I manually perform these calls without pci_register_driver(), instead using pci_get_device() to get the device handle, that the IRQ is set to 0.
As a result request_irq(dev->irq) fails (for obvious reason) and the driver cannot proceed with the initialization.
What step am I missing to correctly enable the IRQs for a PCI device manually?

I don't know what step you are missing, but you might want to walk through pci_register_driver's path and see what it does with its irq field. Also, take a look at pci_request_irq.

This certainly used to work. Are you sure you are looking at the correct PCI device?

I ended up refactoring the driver so that I could use the normal pci_register_driver&probe path to avoid this problem because I could not get it to work, and do not have the time to figure it out.

"I ended up refactoring the driver..." That's how it has to be done from day 1. I don't understand the requirement of having pci_get_device() instead of normal path except some rare corner cases.

Since it is a legacy code base, it would have been quicker not to refactor it.
